# Update data in a separate sheet based on Dates

Tags: date, return-value

I wonder if someone can help me please?

I want to update a separate sheet/ tab within an overall google sheet based on the entries in another sheet / tab and the date selected so for example

Sheet 1 has the data such as

31 May   Name    Emails Allocated   Emails Completed   Emails Remaining
James         100                50                 50

01 Jun  Julia         120                20                 100

02 Jun  John          80                 40                 40

On Sheet 2 I want to be able to select  the date and it will populate that sheet with the above information from Sheet 1 based on the date I've selected.

So if I select 01 Jun it will update with data for Julia and if I select 02 Jun it will update with data for John and so on.

How can I do this please?

Kind regards

Chris

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxwH6.png)

Comment: Hi @Chris Are you looking for help using Python ?

Comment: Python? I'm just trying to update the data in a google sheet. Thanks

Comment: Share a spreadsheet if my answer didn't fit exactly your need.

Comment: Hi Mike, I've tried to make that work but it isn't I'm afraid, I've updated the query with an example picture

Answer (score 0):

On sheet2, try

```
=offset('Copy of Copy of Direct Sales '!$A$1,MATCH($B$1,'Copy of Copy of Direct Sales '!A:A,0)-1,1)
```

other solution with unique formula

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(B1,'Copy of Copy of Direct Sales '!A:L,{2;3;4;5;6;11;12},0))
```

Comment: Hi Mike I’ve updated the query with an example picture would you mind taking a look please? Thanks

Comment: it could be helpfull if you can share a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: I have shared a picture in the original query. Thanks

Comment: Sorry Mike I don't understand what you want me to do? I don't mean to be awkward, i'm happy to do what you need to get the answer to my question. I don't find this site to be very user friendly in terms of sharing information.

Comment: I can share a copy of the sheet but can you do that on here?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10zJEEedsjeEn71CCSfUw2_cEQre0XvAaQdxsPLzJrPs/edit#gid=1704175243

Comment: I have updated my answer (and your sample)